# Self Join Query Doctrine 2 Zendframework 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using Doctrine 2 ORM, Zendframework 2

Entity attribute in Role Entity look like this

```
/**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

   /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Application\Entity\Role", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    protected $children;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Application\Entity\Role", inversedBy="children")
     * 
     */
    protected $parent;
```

Mysql Table look like this.

[image]

Result I am looking for is an array. 
One thing is critical, Any entry in array before apprearing in value must be added as key, 
So order is very important.

i.e [site-manager] => guest can't come as first entry(0 index) if [guest] => will not exist before it becaause guest(value) does not exist in array as key
so [guest] => will come first even if it is entered as second record in table

```
Array(
[guest] => 
[site-manager] => guest
[company-manager] => site-manager
[member] => guest
[staff] => member
[internalstaff] => member
[sales] => staff
[manager] => sales,internalstaff
[admin] => manager
)
```

I am running this code in my controller which is returning empty array

```
$qb = $objectManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('r, p')
                ->from('\Application\Entity\Role', 'r')
                ->innerJoin('r.parent','p', 'with','p.id = r.id')
                //->where('b.id = ?1')
                ->orderBy('r.id', 'ASC');

        $data = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be

```
    $qb = $objectManager->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select('r.name', 'c.name as children')
                    ->from('\Application\Entity\Role', 'r')
                    ->join('r.parent','c');

            $data = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

            $refine =  array();
            foreach ($data as $v)
            {
                if(is_array($v))
                {
                    if(array_key_exists($v["children"], $refine)){
                        $refine[$v["name"]][] = $v["children"];    
                    } else {
                        $refine[$v["children"]] = array();    
                        $refine[$v["name"]][] = $v["children"];    
                    }

                }

            }
 print_r($refine);
```

Will return following

```
Array
(
    [guest] => Array
        (
        )

    [site-manager] => Array
        (
            [0] => guest
        )

    [company-manager] => Array
        (
            [0] => site-manager
        )

    [member] => Array
        (
            [0] => guest
        )

    [staff] => Array
        (
            [0] => member
        )

    [internalStaff] => Array
        (
            [0] => member
        )

    [sales] => Array
        (
            [0] => staff
        )

    [manager] => Array
        (
            [0] => internalStaff
            [1] => sales
        )

    [admin] => Array
        (
            [0] => manager
        )

)
```

You can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function if you wish to flatten inner array